# No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I want to use cmake with "Unix Makefiles" generator. Here is the code I run:

```
cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles"
```

However, it gives me the following error (which is the primary error):

```
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
```

***My question is that what is the desired compiler? I know environment variable but what is environment variable "CXX" and where can I set it?***

Thank you guys!

BTW, I have downloaded Visual Studio 2022 and here is the installation details (maybe this will be helpful):
[Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yheoo.png)

BTW, I have checked the CMakeError.txt and here are the total error messages:

```
  Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
    Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
    Build flags: 
    Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: i think you didn't install the cmake. check cmake --version. it will reflect you the default version of cmake

Comment: The error message also suggests looking for more information in output and error log files. Have you followed this suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to follow the error message suggestions, and set `CXX` environment variable to the desired C++ compiler? Also make sure that the error you show us is the **primary** error, that is no error message has been emitted before it.

Comment: Make sure you have path to C++ compiler in your $PATH

Comment: You **cannot possibly** use **Unix** Makefiles on Windows with MSVC. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thank you guys. I have updated my question to make it cleaner. Please see the update.